# INSTALLING WORDPRESS AS SUBDOMAIN,(blog.domain.com), while laravel 5 is main site. (www.domain.com)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dns

I just created a fully functional laravel 5 application, but the pain of building the blog from scratch for the client is too much to bear. Is there any way I can create a subdomain for the site ( blog.domain.com ) and install wordpress as the blog instead ? while laravel runs normally on the domain

Comment: Why should this be a problem? You just install it in the path for the subdomain

Answer (score 1):

As both are separate application (WordPress and Laravel) and you want to host them on different scope (main domain and subdomain), there shouldn't be any problem.

Just create your subdomain (blog) and point to your WordPress installation directory and point your main domain (www) to your Laravel installation.